# How to build robotium test project with ant?

Tags: android, ant, robotium

I've created a test project with robotium for my project.It works fine while running as Android Junit Test in eclipse.But I need to build my test project with ant now.I searched hard but found nothing helpful to make it.Anyone who can tell me how to do it?

In addition,"android update test-project -p . -m ../Myproject" does generate a build.xml file.However, it only run the installed test and never compile after "ant test".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ant release install -f YourPath/build.xml
```